# Typing variable containing type of dataclass

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-typing, typing, python-dataclasses

Consider following simplified example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Type

@dataclass
class BaseConfig:
    x: int

@dataclass
class BetterConfig(BaseConfig):
    y: int

def get_relevant_config_type() -> Type[BaseConfig]:
    # some magic desides what class I want to use
    return BetterConfig

new_config = get_relevant_config_type()(x=42, y=47)
```

Last line causes type-checker to show unexpected argument error, because it expects only implicit `self: object`. The `object`s and `BaseConfig`s init method doesn't accept any arguments (except `self`), so it makes kind of sense that there is this error.

What would be the correct way to handle this? Is it possible to describe the type better, or is there some other way of fixing this?

Preferrably, solution should:

- keep the ability to dynamically choose which class I use
- the return type of the `get_relevant_config_type` would get checked by type checker to avoid mistakes

if it's possible.

Comment: In your code within your function is it not possible to take x and y and return a class instance instead of a class type reference? That way, type checker would also be happy.

Comment: @Firelord In this toy example it is possible. But in reality, there would have to be some way to get which kind of subclass to use - some mapping between some condition and subclass to use, so it would just move the problem. I could do what you say on the most bottom layer, and have some `Dict[SomeCondition, Callable[P, BaseConfig]]` instead of simpler `Dict[SomeCondition, Type[BaseConfig]]`. That's what I'll have to do if there is no good answer to my question, or avoid typing this.

Comment: @Firelord this is a *very* bad advice: type var is unbound in this case and mypy must point that fact out (and it does). Typevar works if you have it both in LHS and RHS (or bound to generic class with `__init__` or `__new__` containing it for type deduction).

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution I'm using (it's not perfect, but it should be technically correct and usable in common scenarios, and it satisfies the original question):

- Return type can be `Callable[P, BaseConfig]` where `P = ParamSpec("P")`.

One thing that's not clear from such type hint is that P are constructor arguments of the specific type inheriting from `BaseConfig`, but it's still better than nothing, as at least the return type gets annotated. (There would be no way for type-checkers to check the arguments anyway as the `get_relevant_config_type` can return different sub-classes, so it's more of an formal imperfection.)